# Arrays of objects to highcharts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, highcharts

Actually I am new to highcharts. I am having a problem while plotting multiple bar series in using highcharts. From controller, I get the arrays of objects. How i will be able to pass it to data to plot it in multiple series. For example, I have 3 arrays of objects. I want to plot these arrays in 3 different series. How I can be able to accomplish it?

Comment: Have you tried to use [wrappers](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/14-articles/2-third-party-implementation/) for asp.net ?

Comment: Nope @SebastianBochan